# How to disable fps display in ar js/ three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am new to AR.js and working on a demo as shown in the tutorial.
I am trying to remove this fps view on top left corner.

Reference Image:

[image]

My Code is:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Init
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// init renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    // antialias    : true,
    alpha: true
});
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('lightgrey'), 0)
// renderer.setPixelRatio( 1/2 );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
renderer.domElement.style.top = '0px'
renderer.domElement.style.left = '0px'
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// array of functions for the rendering loop
var onRenderFcts = [];

// init scene and camera
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Initialize a basic camera
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a camera
var camera = new THREE.Camera();
scene.add(camera);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          handle arToolkitSource
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({
    // to read from the webcam 
    sourceType: 'webcam',

    // to read from an image
    // sourceType : 'image',
    // sourceUrl : THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + '../data/images/img.jpg',      

    // to read from a video
    // sourceType : 'video',
    // sourceUrl : THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + '../data/videos/headtracking.mp4',     
})

arToolkitSource.init(function onReady() {
    onResize()
})

// handle resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    onResize()
})

function onResize() {
    arToolkitSource.onResize()
    arToolkitSource.copySizeTo(renderer.domElement)
    if (arToolkitContext.arController !== null) {
        arToolkitSource.copySizeTo(arToolkitContext.arController.canvas)
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          initialize arToolkitContext
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// create atToolkitContext
var arToolkitContext = new THREEx.ArToolkitContext({
    cameraParametersUrl: THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + './assets/images/camera_para.dat',
    detectionMode: 'mono',
    maxDetectionRate: 30,
    canvasWidth: 80 * 3,
    canvasHeight: 60 * 3,
})
// initialize it
arToolkitContext.init(function onCompleted() {
    // copy projection matrix to camera
    camera.projectionMatrix.copy(arToolkitContext.getProjectionMatrix());
})

// update artoolkit on every frame
onRenderFcts.push(function() {
    if (arToolkitSource.ready === false) return

    arToolkitContext.update(arToolkitSource.domElement)
})


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          Create a ArMarkerControls
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var markerRoot = new THREE.Group
scene.add(markerRoot)
var artoolkitMarker = new THREEx.ArMarkerControls(arToolkitContext, markerRoot, {
    type: 'pattern',
    patternUrl: THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + './assets/images/patt.hiro'
    // patternUrl : THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + '../data/data/patt.kanji'
})

// build a smoothedControls
var smoothedRoot = new THREE.Group()
scene.add(smoothedRoot)
var smoothedControls = new THREEx.ArSmoothedControls(smoothedRoot, {
    lerpPosition: 0.4,
    lerpQuaternion: 0.3,
    lerpScale: 1,
})
onRenderFcts.push(function(delta) {
    smoothedControls.update(markerRoot)
})
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      add an object in the scene
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var arWorldRoot = smoothedRoot

// add a torus knot 
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.y = geometry.parameters.height / 2
arWorldRoot.add(mesh);

// var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(0.3, 0.1, 64, 16);
// var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
// var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
// mesh.position.y = 0.5
// arWorldRoot.add(mesh);

onRenderFcts.push(function() {
    // mesh.rotation.x += 0.1
})

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      render the whole thing on the page
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var stats = new Stats();
document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);
// render the scene
onRenderFcts.push(function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
})

// run the rendering loop
var lastTimeMsec = null
requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec) {
    // keep looping
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    // measure time
    lastTimeMsec = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec - 1000 / 60
    var deltaMsec = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec)
    lastTimeMsec = nowMsec
    // call each update function
    onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct) {
        onRenderFct(deltaMsec / 1000, nowMsec / 1000)
    })
})
```

**I am trying to remove the fps display but unable to get it**. Adding :
Is there any reference or link for the complete tutorial of AR js using three.js? I want to learn it. But, I am not getting a good tutorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the `Stats` widget.

Remove the lines creating and updating it:

```
var stats = new Stats();  // <-- remove me
document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);  // <-- remove me
// render the scene
onRenderFcts.push(function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();  // <-- remove me
})
```

Comment: Is there any reference for tutorial? I have just copied this code from AR.js examples. I didn't know much about it. How can I learn it ?